# p:picklist gets cached although new values are set

Tags: jsf, primefaces

At this moment I've got a `p:picklist` which uses `DualListModel<String>`. The picklist has to be updated whenever a new entity is selected because the list of attributes changes depending on each entity.

But the values with which the picklist gets populated at first will be persisted even if `onEntitySelect()` gets called again, where I use `setPicklistAttributes()` to change the whole `DualListModel`.

I put `sysouts` inside of the setter and the right values get set by `onEntitySelect()`, but almost instantly the setter is being called again with the old values and my changes are overwritten.

Why does this happen? Is my way of resetting the `DualListModel` inside of `onEntitySelect()` wrong?

`<p:picklist>:`

```
<p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{dashboardBean.picklistAttributes}" var="attribute"
    itemLabel="#{attribute)}"
    itemValue="#{attribute}"/>
```

`onEntitySelect():`

```
public void onEntitySelect() {
  currentAttributes = currentEntity.getAttributes();

  List<Attribute> attributesSource =
  currentAttributes.stream()
      .sorted(this::compareLocalizedAttributeNames)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

  setPicklistAttributes(new DualListModel<Attribute>(attributesSource, new ArrayList<Attribute>()));
}
```

Comment: When do you call onEntitySelect? When do you set the default values of your picklist? Maybe that part of your bean is called again because of a mistake.Please post a [mcve] to get further help.

Comment: The default values get set the first time `onEntitySelect()` gets called. This also is the time I initialize the DualListModel, as you can see in the code above.

`onEntitySelect()` gets called by a `<p:ajax event="itemSelect" ...>`. I made sure this only gets fired once by debugging the whole scenario with IntelliJ.

Comment: [mcve] please like requested in the first comment. Also read [ask] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: There's a typo in `itemLabel="#{attribute)}"`, but it seems unrelated to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize DualListModel on init method which has @PostConstruct annotation. And instead of creating new DualListModel in each onEntitySelect set existing DuaListModels source and target with new ones. Here is a sample:

```java
private DualListModel<Attribute> attributes;

@PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        // initialize service picklist
        List<Attribute> source = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
        List<Attribute> target = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
        attributes= new DualListModel<Attribute>(source , target );

    }

public void onEntitySelect() {
  // create your newAttributesSoruce and Target here then set to existing DualistModel
  attributes.setSource(newAttributesSource);
  attributes.setTarget(newAttributesTarget);
}
```